# Windows 7 Task Scheduler, when computer is sleeping, runs batch file but fails to copy target file from network drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

Windows 7 Task Scheduler runs a .bat file overnight to copy a file from one network drive to another.

Task history reports that the task completed successfully overnight, but the file is not copied. The timestamps indicate the task runs in seconds, when it should take much longer. Wake computer to run task is turned on.

When the task is set to run midday, even with the computer locked before triggering, the task copies the file successfully.

What could be causing the task to fail overnight?

The .bat file has some error handling built in, is there a log I can check to see if any errors are thrown? Or a way to save console output to a file?

Comment: Could we see the `.bat` file?

Comment: In Task Scheduler try setting the program to run to `cmd` and arguments to `/c "c:\your\batch\file.bat"`.

Comment: Network drives are mapped with `net use` only for current user account and only when the user is logged in. In a scheduled batch job it is therefore always better to use UNC path instead of network drive. And of course it depends on the account used for the scheduled task if this account has read/write access to a file on a share on server. By default scheduled tasks run with local system account which does not have any permissions on servers in any network.